# JScrollPane triggering weird AdjustmentEvent when adding components

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm using a `JScrollPane` with a `BoxLayout` (a `Box`, although I've tried a `GridLayout` too) that shows a list of paginated elements, each page has 5 elements and each element has 5 visual components. The data to fulfill the elements is retrieved from a web service, on load an every time the page changes, removing the current elements in the list and adding the new ones (I know this could be optimized but that's what I have for now).

The weird thing here is that, both on load and when changing page, the vertical scroll bar is moved to some position in the middle, not top, not bottom and not exact center. I've tried to move it up programatically after adding the components, but the scroll is put again in that position after the data presentation method finishes. Then, I can use the scroll bar normally, until the next page change.

Actually, I've attached an `AdjustmentListener` to the `JScrollBar` and I can count 25 times (5*5, duh!) that an `AdjustmentEvent` event that moves the scrollbar to that position is triggered - and yes, if I add less components the event is triggered less times.

I have tried calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the window before moving the scroll bar but nothing seem to work, it keeps getting moved to that particular position once per added component.

Any ideas? I'm sorry for not posting some piece of code, but it is kind of a mess and it's difficult to extract the essential parts that could be causing the problem.

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

Responding to @kleopatra, I'll try to make up some code similar to what I'm doing, although maybe I'm skipping *something* that *somehow* causes the strange behavior.

```
public class MyUI extends JPanel {

    List<Data> data;
    JPanel dataItemsPanel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    // ...

    /**
     * Method to build the UI.
     */
    void createUI() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // ...

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        JPanel right = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // ...

        dataItemsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        // this is the scroll pane that behaves weird
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(dataItemsPanel);

        //...

        right.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSPlitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            left, right);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
        this.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // ...

        loadPage(0);

    }

    /**
     * Method to load a data page. Called when the program starts (to load
     * the first page) and whenever the data page is changed.
     */
    void loadPage(int page) {

        data = retrievePageDataFromWebService(page);

        // remove previous data
        dataItemsPanel.removeAll();
        // add new data
        for (Data d : data) {
            // build complex data item representation
            JPanel description = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            description.add(new JEditorPane(/*...*/));

            JPanel options = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            options.add(new JButton(/*...*/));
            options.add(new JButton(/*...*/));

            JPanel leftDataPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            leftDataPanel.add(new JEditorPane(/*...*/));

            JPanel rightDataPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            rightDataPanel.add(new JEditorPane(/*...*/));
            rightDataPanel.add(options, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel data = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            data.add(leftDataPanel);
            data.add(rightDataPanel);

            JPanel dataItemContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            dataItemContainer.add(description, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            dataItemContainer.add(data, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // finally add it to the data panel
            dataItemsPanel.add(dataItemContainer);

        }

        /*
        After this method finishes, an AdjustmentEvent is called once per
        added component (25 times). Trying to set the scroll bar position
        at this point has no effect, as the events are triggered after the
        method. I have tried to call revalidate() and repaint() here and
        then move the scroll bar but the result is the same.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: no SSCCE no help possible (never have seen such behaviour, so my guess it's something in the your code). On the bright side: putting together the smallest example that exhibits the problem is on your path to solve it, you'd have to do it anyway :-)

Comment: create and fill any data from local variable